# classpath specification

Tags: java

i have two programs
one in directory /home/redhat/Documents/java1/j1

Demo1.java

```
package j1;
public class Demo1
{
        public void print()
        {
                System.out.println("hi");
        }
}
```

and the other in directory /home/redhat/Documents/java1/j

Demo2.java

```
import j1.*;
public class Demo2
{
        Demo2()
        {
                Demo1 d=new Demo1();
        }
}
```

when i say

```
javac -classpath /home/redhat/Documents/java1/j1 Demo2.java
```

i get the following error

```
Demo2.java:2: package j1 does not exist
import j1.*;
^
Demo2.java:7: cannot access Demo1
bad class file: /home/redhat/Documents/java1/j1/Demo1.java
file does not contain class Demo1
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
                Demo1 d=new Demo1();
                ^
2 errors
```

i want to access instance of Demo1 in Demo2 
please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your classpath is wrong. You should point to the **root of any declared packages**:

```
javac -classpath /home/redhat/Documents/java1 Demo2.java
```

Other previous step that I miss is the compilation of Demo1 class. Javac compiler will look for ".class" files, not ".java" ones. So before executing that you need:

```
javac Demo1.java
```

As an improvement I would suggest you that you declare your second class inside package "j" instead of default package, since it is not a good idea to have root source paths inside another root path that already contains packages.

Comment: i don't want to put it in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

The classpath option specified in the command line of the javac executable is used to define [the user classpath location](http://download-east.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#searching) where the compiler may find the compiled class files of types. In other words, the compiler expects compiled .class files in the user classpath.

In your case, you have a source class file, in which case you should use the sourcepath option of javac:

```
javac -sourcepath /home/redhat/Documents/java1 Demo2.java
```

javac will locate the j1 package under the user class path and hence resolve the type.